Electromagnetic energy density in dielectric
Poynting's theorem can be interpreted to show that the total electromagnetic energy in a volume from the electric field is
$$\frac{1}{2\epsilon_0} \int_\mathcal{V} E^2 dV$$
However, when using Maxwell's equations in matter, you can instead show
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_\mathcal{V} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{D} dV$$
Which, when expanded, is
$$\frac{1}{2\epsilon_0} \int_\mathcal{V} E^2 dV + \frac{1}{2} \int_\mathcal{V} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{P} dV$$
Evidently, these differ by the second term. Therefore, the term "electromagnetic energy density" must be getting used in a slightly different way in the two scenarios. What is the energy associated with that second term?

The first equation is the total energy required to assemble the entire charge configuration, free and bound, starting from vacuum. The latter  equation is the total energy required to assemble just the free charge configuration, starting with the unpolarized linear dielectric already present. The second equation is what we more commonly mean by the "energy" as we normally only control the free charge with the dielectric present.
The additional term in the second equation represents the work needed to polarize the dielectric. The first equation does not include this because $\mathbf{E}$ only knows about the net (free and bound) charge configuration. Once the charge configuration is assembled, $\mathbf{E}$ is the same as the $\mathbf{E}$ produced by just the free plus bound charge. The rest of the dielectric is "invisible" to it and is effectively absent.
To see this, consider two geometrically identical parallel-plate capacitors, one without dielectric and the other with dielectric, charged to the same voltage. The electric field $\mathbf{E}$ and the charge density $\sigma$ are clearly identical in both cases. What's different is the free charge density $\sigma_f$. The first capacitor has $\sigma_f = \sigma$ while the second capacitor  has $\sigma_f = \varepsilon_r\sigma$. When we normally speak of the charge in a capacitor, we are talking about $\sigma_f$ and not $\sigma$. The obvious conclusion is that the capacitance and stored energy in the second capacitor is greater. If we used the first equation, we would have concluded that the stored energy was the same. Therefore, it is clear that the second equation is more useful.
This is covered in section 4.4.3 of Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics.
